# Prove that $\Phi_{eq}$ has continuum many closed complete extensions.

Tags: logic, model-theory

Full question:  Let $\mathcal{L} = \{E\}$ where $E$ is a binary relation and let $\Phi_{eq}$ be the axioms for an equivalence relation.  Prove that $\Phi_{eq}$  has continuum many closed complete extensions.

This is a practice question for a prelim, which I have no idea how to start.  I think that I may need to use the atomic diagram of a models, but I don't know how to do this.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is a "closed" extension?

Comment: According to my notes, the closure of a theory is $Cl(T) = \{\phi \vert\, T \vdash \phi \}$.

Comment: Ah. Closed under deductions. Very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** For every $A\subseteq\Bbb N\setminus\{0\}\cup\{\infty\}$, write a theory stating that for the sizes of the equivalence classes are exactly the members of $A$. Use cardinal arithmetic to prove that there cannot be more than continuum extensions.

Comment: Thank you @Asaf Karagila.  So for each $A$, let $T = \Phi_{eq} \cup \{\varphi_n \vert\, n \in A\}$ where $\varphi_n$ says that there is an equivalence class of size $n$.  As $T$ is satisfiable and $\vert \mathcal{P}(A)\vert = \text{continuum}$, there exists at least continuum many extensions.  How do I know these are closed and complete?

Comment: No no. You need to do a bit more. First of all, require that there is exactly one equivalence class of each finite cardinality; you also want to conclude the existence of at least continuum by the fact that $|\cal P(\Bbb N)|$ is continuum. As for completions, just complete them all. You still have at least continuum, and you can't have more. So you have exactly continuum.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  Just one more thing.  How do you know that there can't be more than continuum many extensions?

Comment: Well, how many formulas are there in the language?

Comment: Can you write that there's a class of each finite size and an infinite class? I don't think that the presence of an infinite class is elementary if we establish that there are infinitely many classes to begin with. I think all complete extensions can be listed by saying: how many classes of each finite size there are, and how many classes there are in total, and that's it.

Comment: @tomasz: You might be right. I'll give it another thought and edit if needed. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I also think that this theory should have quantifier elimination if we add (definable) predicates for “$x$ is in a class with at least $n$ members”.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Okay, a correction: I don't think the presence of an infinite class can be established if there are finite classes of arbitrarily large size. We can say that if a class has at least $n$ elements then it has at least $n+1$ for large enough $n$. So the complete theories would probably say how many classes of each finite size there are and what's the bound on the size of a class (if any), and if there is one, then how many infinite classes there are. Still, finding $\mathfrak c$ incompatible extensions is far easier than finding *all* of them. :)